# How to return an empty result set if parameter is left blank when exec stored procedure? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I am currently working with this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test 
    @char VARCHAR(MAX) = ____
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE column ___  =  @char + _____
```

And I need to make it so that if the user executes the stored procedure without a value for the parameter, it should return an empty result set. And if they provide a value, then it returns the result set for that value provided.

How would I go about in filling in those blanks?

I figured out how to do it but it would require me to change the code so my way would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test 
    @char VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE column = ISNULL(@char, NULL)
```

I believe this way works, but the question wants me to do it their way, does anyone know how to do it with the way the question has it structured?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The top code already does that if you make the parameter nullable

Comment: Better use if else condition for checking parameter value.

Comment: *does anyone know how to do it with the way the question has it structured* Can you rephrase this ? Also `ISNULL(@char, NULL)` this is just meaning less

Comment: I understand there's other ways to do it but it's wanting me to do it the way the question provided. So something has to go after the @char + as well as something between column ___ =

Comment: This appears to be another one of those nonsensical academic questions that has no real purpose and doesn't work properly anyway. What's the blank after the `column` meant to signify? I can't think of any valid SQL that you can stick between a column and an `=` operator except for `>`. If the first blank is `NULL` and the last blank is `''` it'll probably work, but again, it's nonsense

Answer (score 1):

```
---Try this it's Might work for you
-- SET @char NULL If it's '____' 

    DECLARE @char VARCHAR(MAX) = '____'

        IF @char ='____' 
        SET @char= NULL

        SELECT * 
        FROM Table1 
        WHERE column= @char
```